Emmet expand on tab failing in VSCodium despite apparent correct config
Set file type to html
Type !
Tab
Nothing happens
Backspace
When the ! disappears, the correct Emmet expansion appears briefly, then file is empty
From settings.json
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.useInlineCompletions": true
VSCodium 1.88.1 on Mac Monterey

What exactly do you want to expand into?

The ! Emmet shortcode expands into a basic html template. This is the expected default behavior.
This, precisely:
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
</body>
</html>```

although with line breaks, which don't seem to appear here

Add further info like that to your question by editing it. Then start by upgrading your VSCodium, that version is very outdated, current is 1.95.3. If it doesn't help, try resetting your keybindings temporarily.

Updated, no change. Removed all custom keybindings, fixed.
Sigh. There is a mass of 'editor.suggest' entries in the user settings.json (none of which I recognize, but brain damage has that effect) and this was set to false. Removing it, or setting it to true, fixes the issue.
editor.suggest.showProperties
Considering trashing all customizations I don't recognize, since it's been since preCOVID that this was all configured.
Thanks for pointing me at a solution.
